# QuickFIX: How to change target platform

Tags: iphone, xcode, quickfix

After compilation libquickfix.dylib, and link it in Xcode with my programm, error is:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/marekbaranowski/jmbSoftware/_NOM2/
QuickFIX/libquickfix.dylib, file was built for x86_64
which is not the architecture being linked (i386):
/Users/marekbaranowski/jmbSoftware/_NOM2/QuickFIX/libquickfix.dylib
```

How to change platform to i386, armv7 or both in one dylib?

Comment: I think you can't unless you can compile QuickFIX yourself. Do you have the source / or can you get an alternative build?

Comment: Source is available.  https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix.git

Comment: this is compiled by me from source